# ST3: Any setting to disable this red warning?

Tags: sublimetext3

I think this is related with Sublime Linter but is there any way to disable this red warning line? It’s quite annoying.
I already set the "delay” in 15.0 sec so that the red or yellow dots won’t come up at least while I type, but the same doesn’t go with this red thing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Command Palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html), run *SublimeLinter: Choose Lint Mode* and specify when you want to run the linter. You current setting is *Background*, it runs the linter whenever the text changes. You probably want to change the setting to *Save* or *Manual*.

Comment: seems like that's the choice. Thanks!